# WP7 Callbacks From WCF

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a project that relies heavily on communication between multiple WP7 devices.  I wanted to use WCF callback contracts to create a subscribe/unsubscribe architecture for my services however I have recently found out that I can't use wsDualHttpBinding on Windows Phone 7 but only basicHttpBinding.

Can anyone suggest any approaches using basicHttpBinding which might allow for a similar approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use [Push Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28VS.92%29.aspx) to send the data to the phone (the other option would be polling the server at a predetermined interval which would kill battery life on the device).

Comment: Giving you the answer since you were first.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using (raw) [Push Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28VS.92%29.aspx) to tell the app that there is a new message on the server to retrieve.